# Concatenating unbounded signals in Verilog, (Synthesizable)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I was wondering if you know other logic for the following operation:

Given 7 signals:

`logic [7:0] in0, in1, in2;`

`logic [2:0] len0, len1, len2;`

`logic [31:0] out`

Perform a concatenation of 3 in signals such that

`out = {0...0, in2[len2:0], in1[len1:0], in0[len0:0]}`

0...0 is zero padding. I can only think of
`out = 31'd0 | in2<<(len1+len0) | in1<<(len0) | in0`
but I was wondering if there is another way to do this concatenation. I am okay with a multi-cycle approach. I just wanted to see if there is a faster/smaller area as an implementation for this operation.

Comment: I think what you did think is not also correct. It should have been `out = 31'd0 | ((in2>>(7-len2))<<(len1+len0+2)) | ((in1>>(7-len1))<<(len0+1)) | (in0>>(7-len0))`.

Answer (score 2):

The only syntax currently synthesizable for doing this is mask/shift/or, or a set of `for` loops.

```
out = (in2 & (1<<len2)-1) << len0+len1 |
      (in1 & (1<<len1)-1) << len0 |
      (in0 & (1<<len0)-1);
```

Any way you do it results in a lot of multiplexers.